# Add a block on top order page

Tags: magento2, module, blocks

I like to add a block on top order creation page, in /Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_create_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <css src="Amanweb_Custcomment/css/custcomment.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="content">
        <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Custcomment" before='-' name="items"  ifconfig="custcomment/general/enable" template="order/view/custcomment.phtml" />
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
</page>
```

But nothing is shown.

PS: I successfully added the same block in order view page
In Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <css src="Amanweb_Custcomment/css/custcomment.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="content">
        <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Custcomment" before='-' name="custcomment"  ifconfig="custcomment/general/enable" template="order/view/custcomment.phtml" />
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Template path in your Your sales_order_create_index.xml is not properly declared.

Try to use below **sales_order_create_index.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="content">
        <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Custcomment" before="order_content" name="mycustom_item"   template="Vendor_Module::order/view/custcomment.phtml" />
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
</page>
```

Comment: it works like this 
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="content">
        <block class="Amanweb\Custcomment\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Custcomment" before="order_content" name="mycustom_item"   template="order/view/custcomment.phtml" />
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
</page>

Comment: Adding the Vendor_Module in the template is not required, since we are in the same module

Comment: okay. Thanks for the information.

Comment: Adding the attribute name solved the problem!

Answer (score 0):

It works like that

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> <page xmlns:xsi="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body> 
<referenceBlock name="content"> 
<block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Custcomment" before="order_content" name="mycustom_item" template="order/view/custcomment.phtml" /> 
</referenceBlock> 
</body> 
</page>
```